# Contact form. Message limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have form on my website which is contact form. I am using ReCaptcha on that. 
The form just sending email, no records to data base.

So my question is should i put character limit on that message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to put limits on input fields. For example you could decorate the property on your view model which is bound to the message with the `StringLength` attribute to enforce validation.

```
[StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "The message must be at most {1} characters long.")]
[AllowHtml]
public string Message { get; set; }
```

Comment: currently i have 2000  limit. Alaso i was thinking to deny forward slash ("/") character to prevent any <script><script/> to send `[RegularExpression("^[^/]*$", ErrorMessage = "The {0} should not contain forward forward slash symbol.")]`. But may be it is unnecessary in such case and just [AllowHtml] like you said? What do you think about that?

Comment: @jason, yeah it's very good idea to prevent scripts. It's just that you should not use any regex to do this. You should use the AntiXss library: http://wpl.codeplex.com/. So before sending the email simply feed the Message property through it so that it filters everything that could be dangerous.

Comment: Any thoughts on that?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460512/format-message-from-contact-form