# Format message from contact form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have contact form which is sending email.

But if I type a long message in the text area and after clicking submit, in my email this message displaying in single line.

e.g if i type that in Message text area:

```
My super Mesasge 
My Mesasge Mesasge

From Test.
```

In my email box it will be like:

```
My super Mesasge My Mesasge Mesasge From Test.
```

Why the formatting("/r/n") getting lost and how could i keep the formatting of that message?

UPDATE:
I used AntiXSS.4.0.1
e.g:    model.Message: "sdfsdf\r\nsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdafsdfa"

I did that:

```
    model.Message = model.Message.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
   //result: model.Message="sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdfsdafsdfa"
```

Than:

```
     model.Message = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(model.Message);
    //result: model.Message="sdfsdf<br>\r\nsdfsdf<br>\r\nsdfsdfsdafsdfa"
```

So why Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment added \r\n back? and it is changed also `<br />` to `<br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on how you are sending the email. If you use HTML (`message.IsBodyHtml`) then you need to replace `\r\n` with `<br/>` when populating the `message.Body`.

Comment: @jason, I don't know why the `GetSafeHtmlFragment` method adds `\r\n` for each `<br>` but that should not be any problem as it is still valid html. New lines don't matter in html and if you are sending the email with `IsBodyHtml = true` it will work as expected (i.e. new lines will be preserved as in the original textarea).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of, is that your email format is in HTML, so the the `NewLine` should be converted in `<p></p>` tag or `<br />`